# How do I move an Automator app with embedded workflows to a new location?

Tags: macos, automator

I have created an automator app for batch resizing and renaming of images.
The process is like this:

1. Rename Finder Items
2. Run resize3x.workflow
3. Run resize2x.workflow
4. Run resize1x.workflow

Each embedded workflow duplicates, resizes and renames the original image file.
This all works fine on my machine, the problem is I now want to share this app with other people. When they run it on their machines an error pops up:

```
"The action “Run Workflow (resize3x)” encountered an error."
```

I assume this is because the workflow is now in a different location so the main automator app can't find it. (The same thing happens if I move the location of the workflows on my machine)

Is there a way to embed these workflows in the main app so I can share it, or change the location of these files? Or can I make the links to the workflows relative, so it just looks in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running mac OSX you can use the automater application to automate tasks. Another option on mac OSX is to use applescript by opening  AppleScriptEditor and pressing the red octagonal button to record everything you do.

Comment: I am using the automator application, i'm not sure this really helps answer my question.